# Fastest way to find if element exists in an unsorted array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

Is the fastest algorithm for searching an unsorted array for an element linear search? I mean I guess a combination of merge sort + binary search would be slower. Are there any other options? (in terms of algorithms not involving multithreading)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if the array is unsorted and that's all you know about its structure then the fastest way to search for an element is to consider every one which takes linear time *O(n)*.

If you are going to be searching the array a lot then you may want to consider an initial sort and then insert elements into their correct sorted index (using binary search). This means that you have your initial sort as *O(n log n)* but each insert and search takes *O(log n)*. It's all about tradeoffs and whether that is better than *O(1)* insert and *O(n)* search.

You said no multithreading but that is an easy way to boost performance, have multiple threads look at different chunks in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a method for searching an element in an unsorted array.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> // for 2D vector 
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<vector<int>> vect{ {0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0},{0} }; 
    int count[10];
    int min = INT_MAX; 
    int max = INT_MIN;   
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        count[i] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        //input 7 integers
        int ip,
            rem;
        cin >> ip;
        rem = ip % 10;
        if (ip > max)
            max = ip;
        if (min > ip)
            min = ip;
        if (vect[rem][0] == 0 && count[rem] == 0)
        {
            vect[rem][0] = ip;
            count[rem]++;
        }
        else
        {
            vect[rem].push_back(ip);
            count[rem]++;
        }
    }

    int find;
int flag = 0;
    cin >> find;
    int rem = find % 10;
    if (find>max || find<min || count[rem] == 0)
        cout<<"not present in the array";
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vect[rem].size(); i++)
        {
            if (vect[rem][i] == find)
            {
                cout << "found";flag = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
      if(flag == 0)
        cout<<"not present in the array";
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

I see that this can be faster.
Basically I'm storing the elements in a 2D vector once I receive it.

I'm taking the remainder of the number (number % 10) as the index for the vector and pushing those elements.
Now to search the element, I'm traversing only the elements present in that specific index of the vector.
In this way, the number of comparisons are less.