# Is it Possible to Check Speacial Character in Binary search in java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, stringbuffer

my String Buffer has "_ @ ." .I have Binary Search method that return false for char '.'. i can not find how to check speacial character in Binary Search.Please help to find out this issue .

Comment: Can you post code for `findIn(StringBuffer sb, char c)`?

Comment: I believe you are misusing binary search. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but binary search is used on sorted arrays.

You are trying to perform binary search on array of chars `_ @ .`.
In terms of ASCII codes, that looks like this: `[32][95][32][64][32][46]`.

```
So, when you call your function:
Low: 0 - Middle: 2 - High: 5
Seach: 46 - Actual: 32
Low: 3
Low: 3 - Middle: 4 - High: 5
Seach: 46 - Actual: 32
Low: 5
Low: 5 - Middle: 5 - High: 5
Found!!!
true
```

However, when you take out the empty spaces and run it over `"_@."`

```
Low: 0 - Middle: 1 - High: 2
Seach: 46 - Actual: 64
High: 0
Low: 0 - Middle: 0 - High: 0
Seach: 46 - Actual: 95
High: -1
Not found!!!
false
```

To summarize:

If you are absolutely sure you'll be running your search over a sorted array, then this is OK.

However, like in your case, if you can't guarantee that you'll have sorted array, then don't use binary search.

Comment: it return false ,,my question why can not able to search ,is it possible to search with speacial character ??

Comment: It returns true, but only for this particular case. This is not a good use of a binary search.

Comment: Also, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471511/fastest-way-to-find-if-element-exists-in-an-unsorted-array)

Comment: ,Based on your comment ,we cannot able to search special character in Binary Search .am i right ?

Comment: No, I believe you misunderstood me. You CAN search for `.`. Or `@`. Or any other character that is in unicode table. The problem here is that you are using binary search on an __UNSORTED__ array of characters. Binary search is used on __SORTED__ arrays. Either do a different search (linear, for example) or pre-sort your array.

Answer (score 3):

you called wrong function. change like this..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    b.append(" _ @ .");
    boolean isValid = false;
    isValid = isValueThere(b, '.');
    System.out.print(isValid);
}
```

and `isValueThere(b, '.');` return true.

Comment: This will return true only due to some lucky circumstances with empty spaces.